# Error in R: "Error in tree.control(nobs, ...) : unused argument (type = "class")"

Tags: r, tree, binary-tree, classification, decision-tree

I am building a decision tree using the tree library in R. I have attempted to fit my model as follows:

```
model <- tree(Outcome ~ Age + Sex + Income, data = train, type = "class")
```

Running the above line gives me an error as follows:

> Error in tree.control(nobs, ...) : unused argument (type = "class")

I down sampled so that each class is equal and so did not specify any weights. If I remove the argument, type = "class", the model runs but when I predict using the model, it seems that it is building a regression model which I do not want.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the help page `?tree`  there is no argument called `type`. If you are getting a regression, that is because `Outcome` is a numeric argument. I expect that you can fix this by adding

```
train$Outcome = factor(train$Outcome)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't fix it. I used write.csv to see what my file looked like and turns out that my dataset had a variable called Class (which R created when I used an if statement to combine factors within the variable, Outcome). So other than Outcome, there was a variable called Class.